# can i make my dropdown box defaulted to empty and if i click on dropdown it should the values

Tags: java

hi my dropdown has some 3 values

1)Apple
2)mango
3)grape

when my page loads my dropdown is defaulted to Apple(first value)

how can i make dropdown defaulted to empty and when i clicked on dropdown it should show the values

in java jsf (i am getting dropdown values as List)

Answer (score 1):

I would just add an empty option, and validate as needs be.

Answer (score 1):

I generally add an empty field with a null ID and a value that says something like "Select Fruit". I believe you can have both selectItem and selectItems. So something like this should work inside your JSF selectOneMenu component:

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Select Fruit" />
<f:selectItems value="#{fruitList}" />
```